# onPostExecute never called?

Tags: android

```
public static class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    private String stacktrace;

    public TestTask (String stacktrace){

        this.stacktrace = stacktrace;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Log.i("async", "doInBackground 1"); //this gets logged
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xx:8080/android/service.php");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "logexception"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stacktrace", stacktrace));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("async", "doInBackground 2"); //this gets logged
            return 1;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }

    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        Log.i("async", "onPreExecute"); //this gets logged
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        Log.i("async", "onPostExecute"); //this doenst get logged!


    }
}
```

I've been checking out the other SO threads regarding this, but according to them, my code looks correct as far as i can tell. So why do i never reach `Log.i("async", "onPostExecute");`? Thanks

Comment: Add a log statement to see if doInBackground() actually finishes.

Comment: @RaghavSood `Log.i("async", "doInBackground 2"); //this gets logged` Isnt that enough?

Comment: Oh right. I didn't see that. Sorry. Try removing the @Override annotation and running.

Comment: @RaghavSood tried that as well :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create your `AsyncTask` on `UI` Thread?
Others seems good. Generics and annotations are fine.

So probably problem is that your `doInBackground` method never returns because `onPostExecute` is automatic called when `doInBackground` something will return.

Comment: Its actually called from my `public class CustomExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Well, i guess thats the problem then. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there any way to execute it on my ui thread from my other class?`

Comment: but onPostExecute is synchronized with UI Thread because only this method and onProgressUpdate are specified for updating UI.

Comment: Ok, so i cant pass it as some parameter to the class and run it from there?

Comment: now im not sure but maybe if you can do in your Activity something like this: OtherClass.getAsyncTask.execute(); maybe it will work, so try it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the `super` in `onPostExecute()`

So you code should be like this:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.i("async", "onPostExecute");
}
```

And this should work

Comment: It is useless to call super.onPostExecute... its super method is empty.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask.onPostExecute%28java.lang.Object%29